# Contextual menu. (Android, SherlockActionbar)

Tags: android, menu, listener, android-actionbar

I really need your help. First of all I created a Customfragment which extends from SherlockListFragment. I implemented my own Listviewrow design and for this reason I created my own  BaseAdapter. A listview row contains a checkbox and some textviews. 
My goal was to build a listview which looks and interacts like the Gmail app.
That means if a user clicks on the checkbox the action contextual menu will be activated.

So these are my classes:

```
public class PurchasesOpenFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements
    OnItemClickListener, ListViewContextualMenuListener {

private ActionMode actionMode;
ArrayList<String> purchases = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    purchases.add("Temp 1");
    purchases.add("Temp 5");
    purchases.add("Temp 2");
    purchases.add("Temp 3");
    purchases.add("Temp 4");
    purchases.add("Temp 6");
    purchases.add("Temp 7");

    PurchaseOpenAdapter purchaseAdapter = new PurchaseOpenAdapter(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(), purchases);
    setListAdapter(purchaseAdapter);

    purchaseAdapter.setOnListViewContextualMenuListener(this);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            "Show details of element with id: " +arg3,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

private final class ModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Create the menu from the xml file
        MenuInflater inflater = getSherlockActivity()
                .getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Here, you can checked selected items to adapt available actions
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        // Destroying action mode, let's unselect all items
        for (int i = 0; i < getListView().getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
            getListView().setItemChecked(i, false);

        if (mode == actionMode) {
            actionMode = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        long[] selected = getListView().getCheckedItemIds();

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "elements selected: "
                + selected.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        if (selected.length > 0) {
            for (long id : selected) {
                toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "element selected with id: " + id,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
        mode.finish();
        return true;
    }
};

public void closeContextualMenu() {
    if (actionMode != null) {
        actionMode.finish();
        actionMode = null;
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
@Override
public void onItemCheckBoxChanged(int position, boolean checkState) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "pos: " + position
            + " check: " + checkState, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    getListView().setItemChecked(position, checkState);

    int amountOfCheckedElements = getListView().getCheckedItemIds().length;

    if (amountOfCheckedElements > 0) {
        if (actionMode == null) {
            actionMode = getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(
                    new ModeCallback());
        }
        actionMode.setTitle(amountOfCheckedElements + " selected");
        return;
    } else {
        if (actionMode != null) {
            actionMode.finish();
        }
    }

}
```

}

2nd class:

public class PurchaseOpenAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> purchases;
private static LayoutInflater inflator;
private ListViewContextualMenuListener contextualListener;

public PurchaseOpenAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> purchases) {
    this.context = context;
    this.purchases = purchases;
    inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return purchases.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    boolean checkBoxChanged = false;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflator
                .inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvDate = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listview_purchase_date);
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listview_purchase_title);
        holder.tvSupermarket = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listview_supermarket);
        holder.tvArticleAmount = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listview_article_amount);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listview_checkbox);

        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // TODO only temp data
    String temp = purchases.get(position);

    holder.tvDate.setText("01.01.2001");
    holder.tvTitle.setText(temp);
    holder.tvSupermarket.setText("Spar");
    holder.tvArticleAmount.setText("20 Articles");

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

public void setOnListViewContextualMenuListener(
        ListViewContextualMenuListener l) {
    contextualListener = l;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
    Toast toast = Toast
            .makeText(context, "Checkboxstate of element with positon: "
                    + v.getTag() + " check state: " + cb.isChecked(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    contextualListener.onItemCheckBoxChanged(Integer
            .parseInt(cb.getTag().toString()),
            cb.isChecked());
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvDate;
    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvSupermarket;
    TextView tvArticleAmount;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}

}
```

As you can see here I used implemented the OnClickMethod for the checkbox in the PurchaseOpenAdapter. 
To inform the PurchaseOpenFragment that the state of a checkbox changed I created my own Listener (onItemCheckBoxChanged).

So now i come to describtion of my problem:
I click on the checkbox and the contextual menu appears but checkbox is not checked but if I check the state of the checkbox everything is alright (id and isChecked() are correct).

If I close the contextual menu the checkbox is checked.

If I click on the same checkbox again, the id is completely wrong.
If I remove the listener execution in the adapter class, the checkboxes work correctly.

Hopefully someone can help me. Maybe there is another way to inform the listfragment class.
Thank you in advance!

Since I am a new user I am not allowed to post pictures but I can send them by mail if it is necessary.

Comment: The problem here is not related to sherlockactionbar. The problem is the custom listview. I would google for: e.g. "getview android wrong postion". There are many SO-questions related to this problem due to an implementation error of getView method.